# JIT provisioning and Service Cloud User

Tags: user-management

We've set up JIT provisioning for portal users (mostly internal), and the process is working smoothly. The only thing left that needs to be set by JIT provisioning is "Service Cloud User".

I checked the supported fields here:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_jit_portal_requirements.htm&language=en_US

Doesn't look good. Am I correct in assuming I can't set that through JIT? Is there an easy workaround?

Comment: Can you make it more explicit how you came to that conclusion and which field you are trying to set?

Comment: Setup > Users > Manage Users > Create user
You have the option to assign a "Marketing User", "Offline User", "Service Cloud User", ... 
I'm trying to figure out how I can use JIT provisioning to create users with one of those profiles. I'm not sure what the corresponding field is, but I don't see anything in the documentation that resembles it.